# Create and Edit parallel "bus" lines in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, diagram

Of course I've seen [Create and Edit Parallel Paths in Inkscape - Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1499/create-and-edit-parallel-paths-in-inkscape), but the "Stroke to Path" answer there doesn't cut it for me - because I want to draw "parallel lines" as "bus connections" in technical diagrams, like this poor fellow:

[Inkscape-User - Parallel lines brush?](http://inkscape.13.x6.nabble.com/Parallel-lines-brush-td2888031.html)

> > I would like to have a sort of "hatched" parallel line brush (useful for representing busses in diagrams). This is what I could get to:
> >     * Draw three parallel lines [...]
>
> Can you show a sample image  of what you want? Your description is
>   somewhat confusing.

Well, here is an image then (using inkscape 0.48.1 on Ubuntu):

[image: inkscape14]

I basically want a single path (stroke), which is "styled" with parallel lines (strokes), and which *still* allows for editing through the nodes; as it can be seen on the image, I'm almost there - *except* the "styling" lines are **not** parallel, as there is a distortion (widening towards the ends of the master path). This distortion is a known issue, apparently:

[InkscapeForum.com • View topic - Non-destructive Pattern Along Path ?](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8661)

> Both Pattern Along Path, and its LPE version, skew the objects/paths after aligning them to each node. While this is desirable in maintaining continuity when applying a single shape to a curve, it results in distorting repeated objects at corners.

OK, here is a step by step of what I've tried so far (for full size of the images, copy their imgur link, open it in another tab, and then remove the last `m` from the filename, so e.g. `wHTbjm.png` becomes `wHTbj.png`):

1. Draw a simple line with pen tool - a horizontal path:
   [image: inkscape00]
2. Copy this line three times - that is my "parallel" pattern:
   [image: inkscape01]
3. Select all three lines, and choose `Path` / `Combine`:
   [image: inkscape02]
4. Now all three lines are considered as a single path with 6 nodes:
   [image: inkscape03]
5. Start drawing a "master" line with the Pen tool:
   [image: inkscape04]
6. The final "master" line, that I want to make a "parallel bus", is now made of three segments with right angle corners:
   [image: inkscape05]
7. Select the "parallel pattern" path, and then `Object` / `Raise to Top`:
   [image: inkscape06]
8. Then choose `Extensions` / `Generate from path` / `Pattern along Path`:
   [image: inkscape07]
9. Having set up the resulting window as shown below, I simply cannot get anything resembling the parallel line styling of the master line I had in mind:
   [image: inkscape08]
10. So, dropping that approach - and trying the *other* `Pattern along Path`; for this, we need to copy the "parallel pattern" first:
    [image: inkscape09]
11. Then choose `Path` / `Path effect editor`:
    [image: inkscape10]
12. Then from the `Path effect editor` window, choose `Pattern along path` from the `Apply new effect` dropdown, and click `Add`:
    [image: inkscape11]
13. Once the effect is added, click on `Link to path` button in the `Pattern source` row (*the link refers to the object currently in clipboard, which is the parallel pattern that we copied previously*)
    [image: inkscape12]
14. There we go - *almost* parallel lines styling of the master line, if there wasn't for the distortion towards the ends:
    [image: inkscape13]
15. At least the nodes of the master line are still editable, and the effect follows:
    [image: inkscape14]

Actually, since here the "parallel pattern" path is linked - you can edit that one too (with the pen tool), and the master line style will update accordingly; and I tried turning the parallel pattern lines into curves (so as to compensate for the distortion manually) - needless to say, that works very poorly...

Well - anyone know how to get proper parallel "bus" lines in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's one way (a bit tedious though) - thanks to [Bug #493318 “Clone behavior is broken with style inheritance” : Bugs : Inkscape](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/493318):

- Using pen tool, draw an outline of the "master" line
- Select the master line, Alt-D to "clone" it
- Select the cloned line, set a different stroke color - you will notice it has *no effect* at that time
- Select the master line again, open the Fill & Stroke menu (Shift+Ctrl+F); on the `Stroke paint` tab, choose `?` to unset the stroke (*NB: this is different from the `x` option, which means "set - but no paint"*)
- You should instantly see the cloned line get the stroke color you set previously
- You can now Ctrl-D (Duplicate) the cloned line (*don't clone the cloned line `:)`*)
- Make one of the clones' stroke 8 px wide and black; and the other 4 px wide and white
- Select all (the master and the clone lines) - choose Align, and align vertically and horizontally, so all lines have the same positions
- From the XML editor (Shift+Ctrl+X - as there is no other "object list" in Inkscape), select the master line - and then `Object` / `Raise to top`
- Select all (the master and the clone lines) again - and group them

So right now:

- the master line is invisible, and on top - and it has nodes to edit
- the clones lie below the master line, are visible - but do not have nodes to edit

Thus, if you select the pen tool, you can actually manipulate/edit the nodes of the master line - and since there are no nodes on the clones (and they must follow the nodes of the master), there is the effect of editable "parallel style" line:

[image]

Unfortunately, it's a bit difficult to select the master line (given it's in a group), so one must use the XML editor to select it, before one can edit the nodes with the pen tool (easy enough for a simple example - but I can imagine, a bit tedious in a big document)...