# How to create double/parallel arrows in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create double/parallel arrows to represent a [Natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation). Per the Unicode standard the language for this is "double arrow" (see [Arrow (symbol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(symbol))), but it seems related to [parallel paths](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1499) (though these don't address the arrowhead).

Comment: Hi. Do you know you can copy a character using the Character Map, and paste it into a text object using the text tool?   The Symbol font has this glyph. Make sure after you paste it to set the font to the same in Inkscape. [see example](https://imgur.com/EBzLuXT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach if you need an arrow you can adjust non-destructively.

1. Draw a vertical line using the Pen Tool <kbd>B</kbd>. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will constrain the angle horizontally.
2. Duplicate the line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and with the Selector Tool <kbd>S</kbd>, click and drag the duplicate downwards while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the move vertically.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. This will repeat the duplicate and the last transform giving you three lines. The bottom line will be used as a temporary guide for the next step.
4. Make sure snapping is on, and at the end of the middle line, Click to begin drawing a line at the end node of the middle line to form the upper half of the arrow head.  Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the line about, this will help you constrain the angle. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the line
5. Again, from the middle node at the end, click and begin drawing another line pointing in the opposite direction downwards. Again hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constrain the angle.
6. Click and drag the arrow head until it snaps to the end of the two upper lines. And delete the bottom line.
7. Select all and group.

[image]

Note: if you need a longer line it's possible to select the end nodes and move them holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Now, if you need to bend the arrow, add a Bend Live Path Effect. And hit the button for *Edit on-canvas*.  You can add nodes to the Bend in the middle.  And since this is a live path effect, you can also still adjust the stroke size in the Fill & Stroke panel.

[image]

If there is too much distortion because of stretching, again since this is a live path effect you can adjust the nodes of the horizontal lines to reduce this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best method that I've found:

1. Draw the path, tweaking the width.
2. Add a triangle arrowhead, tweaking the size.
3. Use `Ctrl-Alt-C` to break the object into a path.
4. Repeatedly hit `Ctrl-Shift-G` to ungroup the arrow and then the arrowheads.
5. Delete the more complex arrowhead.
6. Change the two objects to white with a black stroke.
7. With the node tool (`n`), use `Shift-B` to select some pairs of nodes to break off, and delete the path segment between the broken nodes.

Obviously this a rather complex process. Is there a better way?

[image]